# I am getting acess denied error while generating java file through Apollo in android using graphql and apollo library

Tags: gradle, graphql, apollo

This is my app(build.gradle) in which I am using these dependencies

`implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:0.3.2'
implementation "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-android-support:0.3.2"
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'`

This is my project build.gradle

`classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:gradle-plugin:0.3.2'`

`build\generated\source\apollo\generatedIR\debug\src (Access is denied)`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was caused by gradle update to 5.0 or 5.1.1

I was experimenting with gradle kotlin DSL and tried to update gradle to the latest version, which caused this issue with apollo. No issue on gradle 4.10 or 4.10.1 for me.

[image]

I assume that for some reason when building with gradle 5+ some script inside apollo starts to look for a **file** inside generated folder, but in fact there is a **folder** with the exact same name.

P.S.: it also may be simple folder permission issue, try to remove "app/build" folder manually.

P.P.S: you may also try the latest apollo and gradle plugins

[image]